# MySQL Changed Auto Increment to Negative Number

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, negative-number

For some reason on a working table, it suddenly changed the primary key auto increment to negative numbers. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

2147514979
2147514980
2147514981
-2147514982
-2147514983

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Sounds like a 32-bit integer overflow...

Comment: If it were an overflow, the negative numbers would start counting "up" closer to zero.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer is right, and the 32-bits signed integer threshold is at 2147483647 which gets incremented to -2147483648

Comment: @PaulProgrammer D'oh, how about that. Time for me to walk away from the computer for a while.

Comment: yeah, but maybe you guys are assuming all the id's are actually there.   so maybe if a few are missing, an internal representation has not overflowed the the id's getting displayed are overflowed.

Comment: Is there any way to change it from 32 bit to 64 bit? The server is definitely 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

in many conventions, one bit is used as a flag for the "sign" of the number.

10000001  will be like -1  and 10000011  will be -3 whereas 00000011 is 3

note, this is just an illustration.  often -1 is actually 11111111 but that's the principle.

clearly this was not supposed to happen, meaning it's not a user error, but a bug at some level.  like the main mysql code handles the number just fine, but a function somewhere else is overflowing.  This is all conjecture, but as far as the negative sign I'd say it was definitely due to the bit as a sign convention.